# Java: Upload file and get back string (contents) of file

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

Hi I have GWT client with standard server-side Servlets.

- I can upload file from GWT client-side and read it's contents at server-side
- I can send it back to client as String

**BUT**

I have GWT [FormPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/index.html) with action (myModule+"import"). FormPanel invokes **POST** from servlet. Browser then redirects me to **myurl/import** so I can see contents of uploaded file.

This is **not what I wanted** though. I'd simply like to have my String back. I added 
[submitCompleteHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/index.html) to my FormPanel, but it doesn't log any results.

I noticed that servlets have method such `setContentType` so I tried text/html, text/plain ... I don't know what should be there ...

To say it in one sentence, I want to send String back to client from servlet without having browser to redirect me somewhere else. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are submitting a form you get your browser to change navigation. In order to make it work the way you want you have to send the file with ajax. For GWT there is the [GWTUpload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) library that allows you to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If the browser redirects you, it's because you gave a "target" to the FormPanel. By default, it submits within an hidden iframe (a.k.a "ajax upload").

As said [in the javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html#FormPanel%28%29), you have to `setContentType("text/html")` in your servlet if you want `onSubmitComplete` to be reliably called.

`onSubmitComplete`'s *results* is the returned HTML's `body` `innerHTML` so you have to be very careful when sending back values with `<` or `&` in them. The only reliable way to get them back is to *escape* them on the server-side, and unescape them on the client-side. You can either use your own escaping mechanism, or you can use `&lt;` and `&amp;`. In the latter case, to unescape on the client-side, you'd either use String#replace, or create an HTML element, set it's innerHTML with the string you got back, and then get its innerText:

```
public String htmlUnescape(String htmlEscaped) {
   Element tmp = Document.get().createDivElement();
   tmp.setInnerHTML(htmlEscaped);
   return tmp.getInnerText();
}
```

On the server-side, you'd use:

```
escaped = content.replace("&", "&amp;").replace("<", "&lt;")
```

(order matters here if you don't want `<`s to become `&amp;lt;`; also, replacing `<` and `&` is enough, `>` and `"` won't cause any issue here)

In your case however, make sure first that the file's content is "text" and not "binary", as it wouldn't make sense to return it as String could cause issues depending on how you use the value on the client side.