# GWT and Sencha GXT: FormPanel result fails

Tags: xml, gwt, gxt, formpanel

TL/DR: How to load an XML response via `FormPanel` reliably?

---

We have a web application in GWT using Sencha GXT for most of the UI. We use a GXT `FormPanel` to upload a file to a server-side script (which just echoes the file's contents) to get a local file's contents in JS. Eventually this can be done with FileReader, but obviously not in browsers that don't support that.

The `FormPanel` submits its form and loads the result in a hidden IFrame from which the contents are extracted with the following snippet (from `FormPanelImpl.class`):

```js
try {
  // Make sure the iframe's window & document are loaded.
  if (!iframe.contentWindow || !iframe.contentWindow.document)
    return null;

  // Get the body's entire inner HTML.
  return iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
} catch (e) {
  return null;
}
```

We're loading an XML file that way and the problematic line is

```
return iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

because the XML is loaded as XML (and thus not embedded in a HTML wrapper) in a few cases. I tried the following:

1. I used `Content-Type: text/html` originally (oversight in the local PHP test script, error on my part in the production code). Worked in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE (9) where the XML was loaded as XML in the IFrame instead.
2. `Content-Type: application/xml` which would be the correct one for the payload. Now it doesn't work anywhere because we now get the behaviour that originally only IE exhibited in Chrome and FF too.
3. `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`: Not a good idea, it just downloads the file.
4. `Content-Type: text/plain`: I was hoping this would always trigger the HTML/body wrapping and it does, but it also wraps everything in a `pre` element so it now fails everywhere, but that at least reliably. Great.

After a little digging I found out that apparently the GXT `FormPanel` uses the same `FormPanelImpl` from GWT so results are identical for both anyway. And GWT's documentation says (which Sencha wisely withheld):

> The back-end server is expected to respond with a content-type of `'text/html'`, meaning that the text returned will be treated as HTML. If any other content-type is specified by the server, then the result html sent in the `onFormSubmit` event will be unpredictable across browsers, and the `FormHandler.onSubmitComplete(FormSubmitCompleteEvent)` event may not fire at all.

However, even with sending `text/html` the behaviour is unpredictable across browsers if the payload is XML.

Is there a general solution to this? Or am I missing something terribly trivial (I'm looking at GWT for just three days now)?

**EDIT:** I tried prepending `<html><body>` to the file contents so even IE would have a body in the IFrame. Well, it did, but it also resulted in a very, very strange `innerHTML` starting with:

```
<?XML:NAMESPACE PREFIX = [default] ...
```

which the XML parser understandably chokes on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that in general, wrapping XML in an HTML context without performing any escaping of special characters doesn't work reliably. I would expect it to fail at least with an XML document like

```
<a>
  <b>
    <html>
    </html>
  </b>
</a>
```

The approach we took is to just send back a small "OK" message, and then use a separate request to get the (cached) contents from the server.

Alternatively, it would probably be possible to perform HTML encoding/decoding (or Base64, ...)

Comment: Any encoding still creates some pain currently for two reasons: (a) It's GWT, so pretty much just Java-the-language without Java-the-standard-library which means most ways of decoding Base64 won't run. And (b) Encoding is done at byte level, which requires me to figure out the encoding (hopefully UTF-8 but you'll never know) afterwards. Since GWT has no provisions of dealing with that I'm still at a loss how to handle it. At the very least I'd still say it's a GWT documentation problem (as if there weren't enough).

Comment: @Joey: I agree, the (GWT) FormPanel documentation may be missing a few details here (the GXT one even more). We found numerous advantages in using the separate request: It allows easier re-downloading, parallel downloading with a download manager, improved security (having a servlet that mirrors everything you send may be dangerous), ...

Comment: I've solved it now by using the method in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6491785/73070). Which essentially is replacing special characters by HTML entities and decoding on the client side. The only problem I have now is random exceptions in Chrome, but *only* in hosted mode, but that's another question then ;-). Downloading the uploaded file separately would be too much re-working here right now and I don't even know whether we have ways of writing files where it's hosted from the echo script, so I ruled it out for now.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to override the method **getContents** in the class **com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element.FormPanelImpl**.

The code change is to use **textContent** instead of **innerHTML**.

```
public native String getContents(Element iframe) /*-{
  try {
    // Make sure the iframe's window & document are loaded.
    if (!iframe.contentWindow || !iframe.contentWindow.document)
      return null;

    // Get the body's entire inner HTML.
    return iframe.contentWindow.document.body.textContent;
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}-*/;
```

I don't know whether this is a GWT bug or not.

Jordi.

Comment: And how would I get the `FormPanel` to use my derived implementation?

Comment: I opened a ticket http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7535 but apparently they won't fix it cause the doc for FormPanel says it can only return text/html.

Comment: new FormPanelImpl(){
         public native String getContents(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element iframe)/*-{ JSCode }-*/;
     };